# Dynamic 3D Map Visualization Toolkit?

Tags: dictionary, visualization, 3d, dynamic-data

I'm seeking a dynamically updatable, "real-time" map visualization toolkit that would support the following concept:

> A user-controlled pilot's eye view flying above a landscape where the topography is
>   dynamically changing (hills rising and falling, slip/sliding around, valleys opening and
>   filling) in real-time. (Currently just a color-coded landscape surface would be acceptable, although the eventual goal is to overlay terrain/map imagery.)
>
> Another process is dynamically updating the landscape topography data
>   as our fearless flyer passes over it.

There's lots of 3D visualization "explorers" out there, but they all seem to either be limited to a static data set, or require that the dynamic evolution of the data visualizations all be calculated in advance and then strung together as an animation. And flight simulators of course all pretty much assume that the topography doesn't change while in flight.

Technical wishlist:

- Linux
- C API preferred, but open to C++ or Java (or Ada :-)
- Free/Open source preferred, but will consider proprietary
- Performance: Well, I'll try to work with whatever it's got

Answer (score 2):

If C++ is ok, and you don't require something too high level, I'd HIGHLY recommend [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg) for a project like this.  I used it on a project several years ago to display various forms of geospatial data on a globe (vector coastline data, sat imagery, etc).

Do keep in mind you're not limited to writing your entire solution in C++ :)
Our 3D visualization app combined our C++/OSG 3D library for graphics, a Java front-end for the GUI, and some old fortran code for the serious number crunching :O